# Is it possible to have a JQuery Gallery to automatically updated when a new image is added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, auto-update

I'm searching for a gallery, that have the possibility to update the images without changing any code, I don't know if that is possible in JQuery or Javascript.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Note: The website is using ASP.net, I can't use PHP

Comment: No matter what language on the server side :)
`$.get('yoursite.aspx',fn )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume, you have access to server - By using ajax, You can write php script which will get image names from directory in which should be images and script will returns names of images. In jQuery you'll send request to this script and You can dynamically  either update or create a images. Something like:

```
$.get( "yourscript.php", function( data ) {  


         // data is a response which you was wrote in php 

         data = data.split(" "); // assume, data is list of images separated by space => image1.jpg image2.gif etc. , by splitting you'll get array of names


    // Your logic for updating images


})
```

Answer (score 0):

that is possible if you use server side scripting such as php by adding it to the html. the rest can be handled with javascript for the effect.